# Status of Flex and Grails

Tags: apache-flex, grails

Looking to integrate a Flex component with Grails server I found http://www.grails.org/Flex+Plugin and was disappointed to realize that:

1. As written in its description "It's not sure if the plugin works in production mode"
2. Plus Tomas Lin Lesson 2 in his blog post http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/nine-lessons-from-building-a-grails-flex-flash-website/ was pretty convincing

So, I've decided to look further and found http://www.grails.org/plugin/blazeds which is also based on nightly builds that was never released.

Digging a little more I found the following correspondence:

http://n4.nabble.com/Status-on-Grails-and-Flex-integration-td1324342.html

Where it seems that Grails and Flex 3 are old buddies and the only question is whether Flex 4 integration worth the effort.

So now I'm confused, can't figure out what is the current status, and how should I integrate a Flex client component with Grails server:

1. Preferably Using flash builder 3 (no 4 for Linux yet)
2. Performance is crucial, so I guess AMF (blazeDS) would be better than REST or WS

Thanks and sorry for the long question,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

You may try plugin for granite ds. 
http://grails.org/plugin/gdsflex

If you did not stressed on 'performance', than I would suggest REST style. It is independent, and free of problems you may encounter with these DS solutions, such as lazy initialization of collections.